# Using chinese characters in FDPI

Tags: php, pdf, unicode, fpdf, fpdi

I have a pdf template that I write English letters on it and it works fine.

```
$fontPath = public_path('fonts/');
define('FPDF_FONTPATH', $fontPath);

$pdf = new Fpdi();
$template = public_path('template.pdf');
$pdf->setSourceFile($template);

$pdf->AddFont('NotoSans-Regular');
$pdf->SetFont('NotoSans-Regular', '', 9);

$pdf->Write(2, "This is working");
```

- I downloaded [Noto Sans CJK SC](https://www.google.com/get/noto/) because it supports Chinese
- I went to http://www.fpdf.org/makefont/ to convert the NotoSans-Regular (with encoding `cp1252`).

---

Now I am trying to write Chinese letters too, but I have been facing problems.

- If I try  `$pdf->Write(2, "This is working");` it shows me:

[image]

- If I try `$pdf->Write(2, iconv('UTF-8', 'UCS-4BE', '我的名字是约翰'));` it shows me:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How can I wake the Chinese text work with FDPI?

I have seen some people doing it with FDPF but I couldn't figure out how to do it in FDPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Old Way:

I found the [solution buried in a github repo](https://github.com/DCgithub21/cd_FPDF) from DCgithub21 which you can extend and modify like below.

After extending the the classes properly, you can use Chinese characters inside Fpdi

```
$pdf = new ChineseFpdi();
$template = public_path('template.pdf');
$pdf->setSourceFile($template);

$pdf->AddGBFont('arial');
$pdf->SetFont('arial', '', 9);

$pdf->Write(2, iconv("utf-8", "gbk", "会写中文"));
$pdf->Write(2, iconv("utf-8", "gbk", "Can write Latin"));
```

---

In official repo:

```
class Fpdi extends FpdfTpl {}
class FpdfTpl extends \FPDF {}
```

What you need to do is create a bridge class called PdfChinese, so your outlook will be:

```
class Fpdi extends FpdfTpl {}
class FpdfTpl extends PDFChinese {}
class PdfChinese extends FPDF {}
```

---

### The Right Way:

Apparently tFPDF was a better way to do it. Reference: https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/demos/tfpdf-demo/

```
define("_SYSTEM_TTFONTS", public_path('fonts/'));

$pdf = new \setasign\Fpdi\Tfpdf\Fpdi();
$template = public_path('template.pdf');
$pdf->setSourceFile($template);

$pdf->AddFont('Code200365k','','Code200365k.ttf', true);
$pdf->SetFont('Code200365k','',42);

$pdf->Write(2, "会写中文");
```